# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.nn'; 'torch' is not a package on Mac OS

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to get pytorch to work but I keep getting this error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.nn'; 'torch' is not a package

I am using a Macbook, i've tried looking at the other answers on here but nothing is working.

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')
```

Answer (score 3):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.nn'; 'torch' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `torch.py` and try to run it as `python torch.py` or another file has the name `torch.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.

Comment: Oh wow! This happened with a trial program I tried. Glad you answered this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check `conda list` to see if there is PyTorch installed. You should be able to run torch if you had installed PyTorch.

Download link: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Just remember to install CUDA additionally if you want to use GPU instead of CPU.